# Decomposing Functions in Scala Either

Tags: scala

So I have the following function definition.

```
def partition[A, B, C](
    partitionF: A => Either[B, C])
```

Where A, B and C are arbitrary types.

Now I am defining a function to pass in

```
sealed trait Response
case object ThisResponse extends Response
case object ThatResponse extends Response

case object ThisDirection
case object ThatDirection

def responsePartition(response: Response): 
    Either[ThisDirection, ThatDirection] = response match {
  case ThisResponse => Left(ThisDirection)
  case ThatResponse => Right(ThatDirection)
}
```

And then we would pass in that as the follows

```
partition(responsePartition)
```

In the business logic.

Now I am trying to individually acquire the A => B and A => C methods that is defined in responsePartition

So what I am looking for is

```
val partitionFonB : A => B = ??? // This is case of this example would be ThisResponse => ThisDirection
```

and

```
val partitionFonC : A => C = ??? // This is case of this example would be ThatResponse => ThatDirection
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried Right and Left Projections, but I could not get the right types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot, in general case, extract a (total) `A => B` or `A => C` function from a function of type `A => Either[B, C]`. If the function produces a `B` for a particular value `a1`, the `A => C` function won't be defined there, and vice versa.

Best you can do, if all you have is `A => Either[B, C]` is `A => Option[B]` and `A => Option[C]` (use `_.toLeft.toOption` and `_.toOption`).

For your particular case, you can extract `ThisResponse => ThisDirection` and `ThatResponse => ThatDirection` as separate functions to start with, and then combine them to get a `Response => Either[ThisDirection, ThatDirection]` function:

```scala
def thisResponse(response: ThisResponse): ThisDirection = ThisDirection // or any This-specific functionality

def thatResponse(response: ThatResponse): ThatDirection = ThatDirection // or any That-specific functionality

def responsePartition(response: Response): 
    Either[ThisDirection, ThatDirection] = response match {
  case r:ThisResponse => Left(thisResponse(r))
  case r:ThatResponse => Right(thatResponse(r))
}
```

Comment: "For your particular case, you can extract ThisResponse => ThisDirection and ThatResponse => ThatDirection as separate functions to start with, and then combine them to get a Response => Either[ThisDirection, ThatDirection] function." Yes that would work too. But how do I do that without invoking either of the functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here - do you still have a question?

Comment: Nope, i did not get the last edit before i posted my first comment. I think that about clears it. Thanks.